# TS-lint error with document.querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, typescript

When using TS with linting rule to prefer 'for of' loops and tsconfig.json targeting es2018 with ES6 for library, I'm running into a situation where the linting rule is trying to enforce the for of loop, but with a variable which is not iterable and I believe requires looping. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

```
const noTab = document.querySelectorAll('button')

for (let i=0; i<noTab.length; i++) noTab[i].setAttribute('tabindex', "-1")  //TS linting error: Expected a 'for-of' loop instead of a 'for' loop with this simple iteration

for (let el of noTab) el.setAttribute('tabindex', "-1")  //TS error: Type 'NodeListOf<Element>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

Comment: I typically see people do `[...document.querySelectorAll(<selector>)].forEach()` these days

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a static `NodeList`, to which you can use the `.forEach()` method directly, i.e. `noTab.forEach(el => ...)`

Comment: forEach() is working great, thank you.

I'm still confused as to why the original attempt fails? Why is ts-lint trying to enforce a for of loop on a node list which is not iterable? Is that not a bug?

Comment: NodeList _is_ iterable, but you might need to add `DOM.Iterable` to your `lib`.

Comment: @cpplearner Thank you! I added that to tsconfig.json and would immediately compile fine. I was still getting the red squiggly warning in VSCode calling it an error at the time even after restarting the compiler in the VSCode windows. Restarting VSCode itself then cleared it, so apparently tslint or VSCode doesn't update quite the way I had assumed, restarting the compiler in the embedded terminal normally gets things going for me after a TS configuration change.